# selectizejs set active option

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I'm having an issue with selectizejs and it's selected active option functionality.

If you want an example, a good example is the ["Performance" example](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/examples/performance.html) from selectizejs' github repo.  If you clone it and load it, you'll see what I'm about to explain.

What happens is when you start typing in something, Selectize will set the first option as `active` and as you type, if that item does not leave the list, it will stay active until it disappears from the list.  What happens is that when you have a larger group (where the options are actually scrolled within a div below the input) the scrolled div will not select the first option when you match against potentially 100 different options and you end up having to scroll up in the div to get back to the first option.

I'm lazy so I'm not linking a jsfiddle that illustrates this.  Rather I'm pointing to their performance example.  Here's how to demonstrate what I'm talking about with that example.  If you type in `caa` and then push down (to select the second one) then push delete for `ca` you'll see the active option fall to the bottom of the list.  What I want is that every time the person types in a letter, the first option is always selected whenever the list is refreshed.  Here's the example code from their repo:

```
var letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV';
var options = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 25000; i++) {
    var title = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        title.push(letters.charAt(Math.round((letters.length - 1) * Math.random())));
    }
    options.push({
        id: i,
        title: title.join('')
    });
}
$('#select-junk').selectize({
    maxItems: null,
    maxOptions: 100,
    valueField: 'id',
    labelField: 'title',
    searchField: 'title',
    sortField: 'title',
    options: options,
    create: false
});
```

Is there a detail I'm missing?  What I tried to do is below to configure this:

```
        onType: function() {
            //console.log(this.$dropdown);
            var $options = $('.option', this.$dropdown);
            $options.each(function() {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            });
            $($options[0]).addClass('active');
            $('.selectize-dropdown-content', this.$dropdown).scrollTop(0);
            this.setValue($($options[0]).text());
        }
```

This works for the most part except that when I push enter it selects the active item PRIOR to me forcing the active option to being the first one.  Is there a quick way to make this happen rather than digging into the plugin to customize it?  Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out just for someone else in the future.  After analyzing the plugin, I found `setActiveOption` and this works:

```
        onType: function() {
            var $options = $('.option', this.$dropdown);
            this.setActiveOption($($options[0]));
        }
```

Set the active option to the first element.